# How to disable a button during ReactiveCommand execution, then re-enable after finished?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, reactiveui

I wrote a simple Xamarin.Android app that uses ReactiveUI:
https://github.com/oscarvarto/RxCounter/blob/master/RxCounter/MainActivity.cs
The idea is the following:

- The Button should be disabled during the execution of a long running `Task` (or `Task<T>`).
- Click should fire a ReactiveCommand in the ViewModel
- The ReactiveCommand should execute the long running `Task` (or `Task<T>`).
  See https://github.com/oscarvarto/RxCounter/blob/master/RxCounter/ClickCounterViewModel.cs#L22
- After completion of the `Task` (or `Task<T>`) button should be reenabled.

**Current code is working**, but I am relying on a boolean flag here:
https://github.com/oscarvarto/RxCounter/blob/master/RxCounter/ClickCounterViewModel.cs#L13-L18
to notify the button of the moment when the `ViewModel.IOIntensiveCmd` has finished executing.

How could I use Observables or ReactiveUI mechanisms to disable-then-enable a the button during a ReactiveCommand Execution?

For example, **how could I produce an `IObservable<boolean>` that toggles the Button.Enabled flag signaled by the start/end of the ReactiveCommand?**

Comment: ReactiveCommand has an IObservable<bool> IsExecuting. So you can simply do YourCommand.IsExecuting.ToProperty(this, vm => vm.IsBusy, out _isBusy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReactiveUI has a couple of helpers for this:

Bind the command to the button directly in the view (see https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/binding-commands)

```
this.BindCommand(
    this.ViewModel,
    x => x.IOIntensiveCmd,
    x => x.MyButton);
```

Use the ReactiveCommand.IsExecuting (an `IObservable<bool>`).

The IsExecuting observable might be helpful for the button text for example.

Comment: Is this the `ReactiveUI` way (for the MyButton Text)?
https://github.com/oscarvarto/RxCounter/blob/develop/RxCounter/MainActivity.cs#L32

Comment: Does that also disable the other controls bound using BindCommand on the same screen automatically or do you have to disable them specifically using var canExecute = this.WhenAnyValue(?